# How to redirect user after login to the same route came from in laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

I have a payment card. there is a link at the bottom of it that derives guest users to the login page. I want users redirect to the card payment route again after login. can you please help me how can I do that?
by the way I am new in laravel.
thanks for your time guys :X
here is loginController.php :

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\Events\LoginLogged;
    use App\Rules\Recaptcha;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class LoginController extends Controller
   {
     
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('throttle:3,1')->only('login');
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to log the user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            //'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required', new Recaptcha]
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(($request->only($this->username(), 'password')), ['usr_is_admin' => 1]);
    }
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'usr_name';
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        event(new LoginLogged($request, $user));
    }

}
```

here is redirectIfAuthenticated.php middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `intended` method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available. For example :

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
```

Comment: tnx for your reply but it doesnt work for me I already tried that.I dont know why

Comment: I shared loginController and redirectIfAuthenticated middleware

Comment: As I can see in middleware whenever user login it will take user to dashboard on every request. So, Please give a try without using middleware.